# Firebug cannot be opened in popup windows

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, firebug, window.open

With Firefox 16 and Firebug 1.10.4 When I do

```
window.open("about:blank", "ventanaNueva", "scrollbars=1");
```

the `"scrollbars=1"` option disables Firebug and I can't inspect elements neither open console.

In firefox 15 it worked fine. Any advice ?

Comment: I think this problem is in generall with popups which are opened with window.open()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is an issue of this version of firebug, this is solved in Firebug 1.11

check [firebug-1.11.0a4.xpi](https://getfirebug.com/releases/firebug/1.11/firebug-1.11.0a4.xpi) (The actual alpha version at 18 Oct 2012)

Answer (score 2):

Meanwhile, you can can always use **Firefox Web Console** with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>, and web tools by right clicking on the page...